# How to make animation on each rerender? (when new props come)

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-props

I have a react component which has props coming from the redux store. I need to do animation for icon from this component each time when I got new props. I change state when my component gets props on componentWillUpdate(). In this way I can get animation but just the first time, then I already have this class in DOM element and new update doesn't call animation. How I see I have to delete class which provides animation from DOM, but I am not sure when to do it. I don't buttons, I have just props comes and each time when it happens I need the animation. I read that there is a way with refs, but I don't know how to use refs in such situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that the animation which is triggered on receipt of new props is a bounce animation, which is triggered once a `bounce-class` class is appended to the desired HTML element.

1. Instead of `componentWillUpdate`, I utilise the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method, since I wish to call a setState when the required prop is updated. It takes the previous props and the previous state. Let us assume, that the prop which we are watching for changes is `bounceProp`.

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.bounceProp !== this.props.bounceProp) {
      this.setState({ shouldBounce: true });
    }
  }
```

2. React relies on Synthetic Events, which also includes [animation-events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#animation-events). We use the `onAnimationEnd` event on the desired element, to make `shouldBounce: false`.

```
<div
  className={
    this.state.shouldBounce ? "bounce-class other-class" : "other-class"
  }
  onAnimationEnd={() => this.setState({ shouldBounce: false })}
/>;
```

Here the `bounce-class` class which is responsible for the animation, automatically removes and applies itself based on the `shouldBounce` variable.

Comment: Thank you. Just now have read your answer. It is useful. I found a way to make it with a unique key.  It also works for my icon, but I believe using animation-events is better.